# Firebase keeps giving me this error .where(...).update is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a simple firebase query using nodejs and firebase. Everytime i run this query i keep getting  db_coll.where(...).update is not a function . I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Below is mu code.

```js
const db_coll =  db.collection('orders');


db_coll.where('store_id', '==', storeId)
    .update({is_confirmed: 1})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Documents successfully updated!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error updating documents:', error);
    });
```

Comment: You can't update all of the documents that would result from a query.  You have to perform the query, read and iterate the documents, and update them individually.